# How can I smooth this surface?

Tags: modeling

I would like to render this surface smooth like a natural curve but don't know how I can geometriccaly transform the mesh. Thanks for your help. Maybe I could add one edge between each segment but I don't know how to do that geometrically.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on your interpretation on "smooth" you might need to rebuild the shape with better resolution (the outline is a bit jagged, consisting of 5 segments) or use subdivision surface modifier that divides the mesh into smaller and smoother polys everywhere. Also I see the edge split modifier has small enough angle to cause the sharp line along the curve where you see the border between light and dark grey. If you increase the angle in the modofer or disable it the sharp line will be smoothed.

Comment: By "smooth" I mean a surface without edge. I agree I have no choice but rebuild the shape. I thought I could add one edge or more between each segment. I don't know how do do that.

Comment: You could add loopcuts to the segments but that won't smooth the shape automatically either. The amount of work you'd put into rounding by resizing the new segments around a common center point would totally exceed the effort to rebuild such a simple mesh with more segments from the start.

Comment: @ metaphor_set. What is the more efficient way to build this shape? Because to obtain it I have copied faces from a sphere but I'm sure there is another way to build it.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a loop cut in-between each of that triangular faces.

You can do that by selecting these 3 edges and subdividing them.

[image]

Select the new vertices on the corner edge and the vertices on the triangle at the bottom. Press J.

[image]

Afterwards, remove the original edges

[image]

The subsurf modifier will work much better now!

Comment: How do you subdivise the 3 top edges?

Comment: Edited answer. Look again